# Slim Respect Validation issue

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

Respect\Validation\Validator. I have a validator class
**validator.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\http\validations;
use Respect\Validation\Validator as Respect;
use Respect\Validation\Exceptins\NestedValidationException;

class Validator {

    protected $errors = [];
    public function validate($request, array $rules){
        foreach ($rules as $field => $rule) {
            try{
               $rule->setName(ucfirst($field))->assert($request->getParam($field)); 
            } catch (NestedValidationException $ex) {
                $this->errors[$field] = $ex->getMessages();
            }

        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function failed(){
        return !empty($this->errors);
    }
}
```

Then I'm using this validation in the controller and here is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace app\http\controllers\v1;


use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;
use Respect\Validation\Validator as v;

use app\providers\v1\CompanyServiceProvider;

class CompanyController extends BaseApiController {

    public $companyServiceProvider;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->companyServiceProvider = new CompanyServiceProvider();
    }

    public function saveBasicDetails(Request $request, Response $response) {
        $validator = new \app\http\validations\Validator();
        $validation = $validator->validate($request, [
            'company_name' => v::notEmpty()->alpha()
         ]);

        if($validation->failed()){
            print_r($validation); die;
        }

        $result = $this->companyServiceProvider->saveBasicDetails($request);
        return BaseApiController::returnResponse($response, $result);
    }

}
```

Here is my route, I'm calling saveBasicDetails function from the route.

```
$app->post('/save-basic-details', \app\http\controllers\v1\CompanyController::class. ':saveBasicDetails');
```

I'm getting following error : **These rules must pass for Company_name**

I wanted to return validation errors in JSON.

Comment: you need to set `$this->validator` to your validator from the container. it's null, so I'm guessing you didn't do that

Comment: From where is the `saverUserDetails` Method? Please add some more code. I think the issue is, that you can't access the container within youe `saveUserDetails` Method.

Comment: I'm calling saveUserDetails method from the route. I also have updated that code.

Comment: Okay, please show your `CompanyController` Class. I think there'll be the issue.

Comment: I have updated my question. Because container concept was confusing little bit. So I have removed this. I have put my controller code.

Answer (score 1):

In the controller you have to inject the container in the constructor, then define a getter to get your validator. check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176059/dependency-injection-in-slim-framework-passing-container-into-your-own-classes), in slim so far there is nothing like symfony autowire you have to explicitly inject the container and get the service you need afaik. Check this code below will help you!

```
//use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;


/**
 * @param ContainerInterface $container
 */
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $this->container = $container;
}


//Then define a getter

/**
 * @return Validator
 */
protected function getValidator()
{
    if (!$this->validator instanceof Validator) {
        $this->validator = $this->container->get('Validator');
    }

    return $this->validator;
}


//Then access the validator
$this->getValidator()->validate...
```

Comment: I removed the container concept 
public function saveBasicDetails(Request $request, Response $response) {
        $validator = new \app\http\validations\Validator();
        $validation = $validator->validate($request, [
            'company_name' => v::notEmpty()->alpha()
         ]);
        
        if($validation->failed()){
            print_r($validation); die;
        }

        $result = $this->companyServiceProvider->saveBasicDetails($request);
        return BaseApiController::returnResponse($response, $result);
    }

Comment: I have removed the container concept. But still getting error but different error.

Comment: I'm getting following error : These rules must pass for Company_name

Answer (score 0):

Guys I made a silly mistake there was a spelling mistake in

```
use Respect\Validation\Exceptins\NestedValidationException;
```

Changed to

```
use Respect\Validation\Exceptions\NestedValidationException;
```

Fixed my issue.